# How to convert gulp setup project to normal angular js project without gulp

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp

How can I convert a gulp setup project to normal angular js project without gulp?.

My friend gave me gulp setup project but I need to be able to run it without gulp.

Comment: Which angular version and are you using gulp build task for running it

Comment: Angularjs Version 1

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to use a different build tool, just remove the Gulpfile and any npm dependencies related to gulp. Then install and setup the other build tool.

If you're not going to use a build tool at all, you do the same as above, but have to manually include all the .js files in your html file separately.

I don't suggest you use the latter of the two. Actually, I suggest you keep gulp, as it's a pretty decent tool.

Comment: yes.. But modify some component and module its working only **GULP SERVE** but not working in **GULP SERVE:DIST**.How can i resolve the issues.

Comment: That's impossible to tell without knowing anything about your code. I suggest you to find a good gulp tutorial and follow that thoroughly. Not only will it help you with this issue, but you'll know exactly what is going on and in addition be able to write "know Gulp" on your resumé. ;-) Win-win.

Comment: Thank you.. Nikolaj

Comment: No problem, hope it helped. :-) Alternatively, you could learn a different build tool and use that instead, then the removal process of my answer still applies.

Answer (score 0):

You must have been using gulp for css minifying or some other tasks you can directly remove gulpfile.js file and run the angular project. It is not a problem having gulp it provides many tasks which reduces development effort unless if you trying to migrate to webpack or browserify tools i don't recommend you to delete.